# Select drop down not showing (jquery-chosen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

Pretty straightforward i'm using the chosen plugin with jquery steps, and I can't see the dropdown. When I click on it nothing happens. I'm not sure why maybe css conflict?

http://jsfiddle.net/y7BT7/18/

```
<div id="wizard">
    <h1>First Step</h1>
    <div>
<div>

<select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" tabindex="5">
            <option value=""></option>
            <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
              <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
              <option>New York Giants</option>
              <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
              <option>Washington Redskins</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
              <option>Chicago Bears</option>
              <option>Detroit Lions</option>
              <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
              <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC SOUTH">
              <option>Atlanta Falcons</option>
              <option>Carolina Panthers</option>
              <option>New Orleans Saints</option>
              <option>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC WEST">
              <option>Arizona Cardinals</option>
              <option>St. Louis Rams</option>
              <option>San Francisco 49ers</option>
              <option>Seattle Seahawks</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC EAST">
              <option>Buffalo Bills</option>
              <option>Miami Dolphins</option>
              <option>New England Patriots</option>
              <option>New York Jets</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC NORTH">
              <option>Baltimore Ravens</option>
              <option>Cincinnati Bengals</option>
              <option>Cleveland Browns</option>
              <option>Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC SOUTH">
              <option>Houston Texans</option>
              <option>Indianapolis Colts</option>
              <option>Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
              <option>Tennessee Titans</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC WEST">
              <option>Denver Broncos</option>
              <option>Kansas City Chiefs</option>
              <option>Oakland Raiders</option>
              <option>San Diego Chargers</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>


        </div></div>

    <h1>Second Step</h1>
    <div>Second Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this working fiddle, I had found a solution for you,

http://jsfiddle.net/y7BT7/20/

execute the `steps()` first before `chosen()`

```
$("#wizard").steps();
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```